# jQuery Ajax Cross Browser with API key

Tags: jquery, ajax, api-key

Can someone please help me about this one?

I have external link with API key where data is located. Format of the data is like this:

> [{"id":"1","name":"John","birth_date":"2014-03-03","general_status":"status","other_status":"iother","job":"manager","api_key":"special_key"}]

Example link: ( I can't put the real link )

> http://example.com/employers?key=special_key

How can I access this data using jQuery ajax "get" or "post" method? I tried with this but with no success:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/employers?key=special_key",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){
        console.log( a, b, c );
    }
});
```

I have also tried with JSONP, POST and with some other variations which I found here on the Stackoverflow.

P.S.

Using postman (Google Chrome extension) I successfully gathered information

Thank you!

Comment: The API needs to set it's CORS headers up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rich. Does this means that it's not problem with me, but with them and theirs API? Just to be sure ...

Comment: If JSONP isn't supported, then yes - they need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header up, probably with a value of `*`. You can get round this by instead using AJAX to get a URL from your server, which will get the response on your behalf (e.g. you AJAX request a PHP file which uses CURL to get the API and just echoes it out).